# checkbox validation if the checkbox is displayed only

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox which is displayed in certain cases. I would like to check that the checkbox is checked only in case it's displayed, for other cases I would like the form to be submitted on click on the submit button. I wrote the following function, but it doesn't work:

```
function checkTheBox() {
window.onload = function() {
var visible = document.getElementById("checkbox").isDisplayed();
if(!visible)
    return true;
else if(visible){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
    if(checkbox.checked)
        return true;   }
    else{
        alert('You must agree to the terms first.');
        return false;
    }
}; }
```

These are my html elements:

```
  <div class='input-block' id='div_checkbox' style='display: none;'> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="0">
  <b>I agree to all terms and conditions</b><br />
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what about, if some visitor of your page removes that checkbox via console?

Comment: Legionar is right, that could be a risk. Always validate your data server-side as well. But also "doesn't work". How exactly? Do you get an error in the console? Or does it behave in a way you don't expect?

Comment: ok, I will validate it on server side. The form is being submitted without checking the checkbox, I don't have any errors in the console

Comment: You can check it on client side as is mentioned in my answer, and then also check it on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check, if that element is `undefined`:

But be careful, user can **remove** your checkbox via console, and will be able to submit your form without checking the checkbox.

Also you don't have to use `window.onload = function() { ... }`, simply use this code and call function `checkTheBox` on form submit:

```
function checkTheBox() {
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox") === 'undefined') {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

    if (checkbox.checked) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      alert('You must agree to the terms first.');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

But as @ADyson said, always validate your data on **server side**.

Comment: to add to this. In case you are using jQuery. `if( $(<elementSelector>).is(':visible')) {....} else{ ;}`

Comment: jQuery tag is not mentioned, also OP's code is all in plain JavaScript...

Comment: Thank you Legionar! it's not validating the checkbox, I will work on the server side as well. :) thanks again for the prompt response